# How to publish checkin at a custom place (like foursquare)

Tags: android, facebook

I referred https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/location_tagging/

While trying to publish checkin, I passed place as place=(some url like "http://www.example.com/jeffys_burgers.html") along with lat,long coordinates and facebook user_id from android app,it 
responds  {"error":{"message":"(#100) Requires a valid Place Page ID","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}.

My query is how to specify actions,object type in my facebook app so that I can pass appropriate arguments from android app, for publishing checkin at a custom place ?

Comment: Show some code that you have tried

Comment: String customPlace="http://<mydomain>/fbPage.php?lat="+lt+"&long="+ln;

   Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
   parameters.putString("access_token", access_token);
  parameters.putString("description",  " My Checkin");
 JSONObject coordinates = new JSONObject();
           coordinates.put("latitude", lt+"");
           coordinates.put("longitude", ln+"");
            parameters.putString("coordinates",coordinates.toString());
            parameters.putString("place", customPlace);
 response = facebookClient.request("me/checkins",parameters , "POST");

Comment: In HTML:
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# coditest: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/app_name#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="my_app_id" /> 
  <meta property="og:type"   content="app_name:checkin" /> 
  <meta property="og:url"    content="http://www.google.com" /> 
  <meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Checkin" /> 
  <meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 
  

<meta property="place:location:latitude"  content="<? $lat ?>"> 
<meta property="place:location:longitude" content="<? $lng ?>">

Answer (score 4):

In the documentation you link to (in the section "Specifying Object Type") they create an object type called "Venue" of the type "Place". You have to do something similar. You don't have to call it "Venue" though.

[image: Screenshot]

Remeber that the object type Place is a "Facebook Place". Your jeffys_burgers.html should have og:type=yournamespace:venue (if you decide to call your object type "Venue"), and have the place:location:latitude and place:location:longitude set.

Comment: I defined an object type with name "Checkin" as above,got the meta properties from "Get Code" link.I put meta properties in my html & also set place:location properties with actual locations that I got.I passed place as place=(my html) along with lat,long coordinates. Still it responds {"error":{"message":"(#100) Requires a valid Place Page ID","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}.

Comment: Thank you Joakim, your info was useful to  me.